# c# autocomplete combobox behaviour

Tags: c#, combobox

I beleive this happen to someone else but i didn't find any post with the same problem.

I have a combobox in a winform with AutoCompleteMode set to suggest and AutoCompleteSource to ListItems.

On 98% of the systems using the app, everything is ok. On the other 2%, i cant find a way to get it work well.

98% = type in combobox something like 359 and all a list of items starting with 359 appear.

2% = type in combobox something like 359 and show nothing BUT if i only type 35 then i got a full list of items starting with 35 then i can scroll to get the 359.

Same behaviour happen on XP and win7 machines. I tried Suggest mode, Append mode and SuggestAppend mode but still have the same problems.

If anyone can help me on this i would appreciate !

Comment: Can you provide some code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Well i could bring the code for loading dataset from DB in the combobox. If it could help i can post it. For the combobox, i set it by properties in VS 2010. But maybe i just don't understand what you want me to bring.

Comment: Can you provide details of the system specs where it works versus those where it doesn't? Are all Windows updates applied? What versions of the framework are installed? There isn't enough information here to provide assistance and you haven't technically asked a question.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, i think you put me on a path. They all have the same framework but not the same SP. Just check the XP one and discover that some are SP2 and some are SP3 and the SP2 aren't working properly. I will upgrade them to SP3 then i will see if it fix this behaviour.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to help. Don't forget to update the question and provide your answer if it works.